# DeleteCases depending on all elements

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have a listed of Tupels

```
list = {{10, 5}, {20, 4}, {20, 3}, {10, 6}};
```

If there are two elements a and b for which

```
a[[1]] <= b[[1]] && a[[2]] <= b[[2]]
```

then I would like to delete the element a.
If I implement this via for loops,

```
For[i = Length@list, i > 0, i--,
  For[j = Length@list, j > 0, j--,
        If[i != j && list[[i, 1]] <= list[[j, 1]] && list[[i, 2]] <= list[[j, 2]], list = Delete[list, i]; Break[];];
    ];
  ];
```

then this works but seems to be quite slow. As I need to implement this for many elements, I thought there could be a better/more performant way to solve this directly with Mathematica functions, like DeleteCases. Do you have an idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
list = {{10, 5}, {20, 4}, {20, 3}, {10, 6}};
```

**1.** You can use the function `` Internal`ListMin `` as follows:

```
- Internal`ListMin[-list]
```

> ```
>  {{20, 4}, {10, 6}}
> ```

**2.** You can also use `DeleteDuplicates`:

```
DeleteDuplicates[ReverseSort@list, And @@ Thread[GreaterEqual[##]] &]
```

> ```
> {{20, 4}, {10, 6}}
> ```

**3.** ... and [`SequenceReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceReplace.html):

```
 SequenceReplace[Sort @ list, 
  {a__} /; (And @@ Thread[LessEqual[a]]) :> Last[{a}]]
```

> ```
> {{10, 6}, {20, 4}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer! In the second alternative, I could not obtain your result but, instead, only the first three elements of the original list. Regarding the first alternative: is it possible to apply this to other nested lists to, e.g.  to list = {{{10, 5}}, {{20, 4}}, {{20, 3}}, {{10, 6}}};?

Comment: @fravity. re the second method it could be version/os related (I am using version 11.3 on Windows 10). Re the first method with nested lists, you can apply ``Internal`ListMin`` after processing the nested list into a list of pairs, e.g. `list1 = {{{10, 5}}, {{20, 4}}, {{20, 3}}, {{10, 6}}};
list = Join @@ list1;` and then ``-Internal`ListMin[-list]``.

Comment: Thanks! I added the extra step and finally used DeleteCases[] to remove all elements which do not correspond to the maximum. Now that's almost ten times faster, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the list into ascending order using plain old `Sort`, and then [`Split`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html) it into sublists where the second element is ascending. The `Last` element of each such sublist will be the one you want to keep:

```
Last /@ Split[Sort[list], #1[[2]] <= #2[[2]] &]
(* {{10, 6}, {20, 4}} *)
```

If you need the operation to keep the remaining elements in their original order, you can sort again based on [`PositionIndex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html).

```
SortBy[
 Last /@ Split[Sort[list], #1[[2]] <= #2[[2]] &],
 PositionIndex[list]]
(* {{20, 4}, {10, 6}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
f = Last /@ DeleteCases[{{__}}] @ GatherBy[Sort @ #, First]&;
```

`list` like in question

```
list = {{10, 5}, {20, 4}, {20, 3}, {10, 6}};

f @ list
```

{{10, 6}, {20, 4}}

A more complicated list (with single elements like `{15, 0}`)

```
list = {{10, 5}, {20, 4}, {20, 3}, {10, 6}, {10, 8}, {15, 0}, {16, 0}};

f @ list
```

{{10, 8}, {20, 4}}

Answer (score 2):

```
l = {{10, 5}, {20, 4}, {20, 3}, {10, 6}};
```

---

Using the third argument of `GroupBy`:

```
Values[Sort@GroupBy[ReverseSort@l, First, If[Length@# > 1, #[[1]], Nothing] &]]
```

*Result*:

> {{10, 6}, {20, 4}}

Or using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[Sort@l, s : {a_, b_} /; And @@ Thread[LessEqual[s]] :> s[[-1]]]
```

*Result*:

> {{10, 6}, {20, 4}}